# Using AND clause in a GPath groovy statement to get all xml nodes matching >1 criteria

Tags: xml, xpath, groovy, gpath

I am a newcomer to Groovy / GPath and am using it with RestAssured.  I need some help with syntax for a query.

Given the following xml snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SeatOptions FlightNumber="GST4747" AircraftType="737" NumberOfBlocks="2" Currency="GBP" Supplier="ABC">
  <Seat Num="1A" Availabile="true" BandId="1" Block="1" Row="1" AllowChild="false" />
  <Seat Num="1B" Availabile="true" BandId="1" Block="1" Row="1" AllowChild="false" />
  <Seat Num="1C" Availabile="true" BandId="1" Block="1" Row="1" AllowChild="false"/>
  <Seat Num="1D" Availabile="true" BandId="1" Block="2" Row="1" AllowChild="false" />
  <Seat Num="1E" Availabile="true" BandId="1" Block="2" Row="1" AllowChild="true" />
  <Seat Num="1F" Availabile="true" BandId="1" Block="2" Row="1" AllowChild="true" />
</SeatOptions>
```

I can extract all seat numbers as follows:

```
List<String> allSeatNos = response.extract().xmlPath().getList("**.findAll { it.name() == 'Seat'}.@Num");
```

How can I extract all seat numbers where AllowChild="true" ?

I have tried:

```
List<String> childSeatNos = response.extract().xmlPath().getList("**.findAll { it.name() == 'Seat' & it.@AllowChild() == 'true'}.@Num");
```

It throws:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path '**'.findAll { it.name() == 'Seat' & it.@AllowChild() == 'true'}.'@Num' is invalid.
```

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `&&` for logical `AND` operator, not single `&` which is a bitwise "and" operator. Also change your expression to:

```
response."**".findAll { it.name() == 'Seat' && it.@AllowChild == 'true'}*.@Num
```

- use `it.@AllowChild` to refer to a field (not `it.@AllowChild()`)
- use spread operator `*.@Num` to extract `Num` fields to a list (not `.@Num`)

Following code:

```
List<String> childSeatNos = response.extract()
        .xmlPath()
        .getList("response."**".findAll { it.name() == 'Seat' && it.@AllowChild == 'true'}*.@Num");
```

produces list:

```
[1E, 1F]
```

Comment: thanks, that makes sense. However I'm still receiving an IllegalArgumentException so I guess there remains some syntactical error somwehere within the statement

Comment: @Steerpike I've found two more syntactic errors in your expression, answer updated